# No consigo subir un archivo a google drive por python

Tags: python, google-drive

he conseguido tanto leer los datos que hay en mi servidor de google drive y descargar archivos, pero no he conseguido como subir.(Todo esto a través de python)

Este es mi codigo
`    from **future** import print_function
import pickle
import os.path
from google_drive_downloader import GoogleDriveDownloader as gdd
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from apiclient.http import MediaFileUpload

```
 # If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.pickle.
 SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly']
def main():
    file_metadata = {'Photho1': 'photo.jpg'}
    media = MediaFileUpload('C:/Users/Jose Maria/Desktop/photo1.jpg', mimetype='image/jpeg')
    file = drive_service.files().create(body=file_metadata,
                                        media_body=media,
                                        fields='id').execute()

main()`
```

Y me aparece es sigiente error:

```
raceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Jose Maria/Desktop/Programación/Python/Drive/Subir.py", line 20, in <module>
    main()
  File "c:/Users/Jose Maria/Desktop/Programación/Python/Drive/Subir.py", line 16, in main
    file = drive_service.files().create(body=file_metadata,
NameError: name 'drive_service' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo tuve exactamente el mismo problema tiempo atrás y buscando en foros recuerdo que el problema era el nombre del objeto `drive_service`, había que cambiarlo solo por una palabra, no recuerdo si era `service` o `drive`, pero luego de cambiarlo el error desapareció, espero que te sirva de ayuda. En resumen:

Intenta cambiar

```
file = drive_service.files().create(body=file_metadata,
                                        media_body=media,
                                        fields='id').execute()
```

Por:

```
file = service.files().create(body=file_metadata,
                                        media_body=media,
                                        fields='id').execute()
```

O por:

```
file = drive.files().create(body=file_metadata,
                                        media_body=media,
                                        fields='id').execute()
```

Comment: Porque me funcionó a mí, tenía el mismo problema y leí en un foro que cambiara ```drive_service``` por uno que era una sola palabra, no recuerdo cuál de los dos era y por eso puse  ambas opciones. Lamentablemente no sé porqué no funciona el ejemplo que trae ```drive_service```, espero que al igual que mí el cambio ayude al que pregunta,

Comment: Listo, buena idea

Comment: Lo siento no me funciona me salta el siguiente error:  NameError: name 'drive' is not defined.   Cual eran las librerias que usted utilizo?

Comment: (Si puede) Podria pasarme su codigo para ver si funciona?

Comment: Ya no tengo la computadora en la que había hecho ese código, lo usaba para crear y bajar archivos JSONs a un drive. Sin embargo, encontré el link de SO de cuando estaba buscando soluciones con el explorador de mí teléfono. Es este: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53616385/nameerror-name-drive-service-is-not-defined-google-api

Answer (score 0):

Lo siento no me funciona me salta el siguiente error: NameError: name 'drive' is not defined. Cual eran las librerias que usted utilizo?